# Отправка сообщения discord ботом на python

Tags: python, бот, discord, sendmessage

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()

async def sender(text):
    channel = client.get_channel(id=***)
    await channel.send(text)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot ready')
    await sender('Hello')

token = '***'

client.run(token)
```

`Кто имеет опыт в разработке бота в дискорде, помогите написать функцию, при вызове которой бот писал переданный текст в определенный канал на сервере. Функцию для отправки сообщений я написал (sender), я не могу понять, как вызывать её в коде. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

1. Импортируем `asyncio`
2. Создаем асинхронную функцию для отправки сообщения - `sender()`
3. Вызываем функцию через `asyncio`, передавая нужные аргументы:

   `asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(sender(762470056040330836, 'test'), client.loop)`

*В данном случае `760470076070690836` - id текстового канала, а `'test'` - сообщение*.

Используя эту строку можно в любой момент вызвать функцию для отправки сообщения.

---

Пример кода:

```
import discord
import asyncio

client = discord.Client()

async def sender(channel_id: int, msg):
    channel = client.get_channel(channel_id)
    await channel.send(msg)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(sender(760470076070690836, 'test'), client.loop)

client.run('token')
```

Как только бот будет готов к работе (функция `on_ready()`), в канал будет отправлено сообщение 'test'